# creating two threads which simultaneously listen for two socket connection.

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

I am going to create two threads which will listen for two socket connections, each thread will have connected with each socket, and will receive the data, but one thing here should noted that it will runs simultaneously and will fetch the data forever. Example:

**THREAD 1**

```
Thread {
    //fetch data from socket 1234
}
```

**THREAD 2**

```
Thread 2 {
    //fetch data from socket 5678
}
```

Comment: use asyctask rather than doing net work communicate on ui thread

Comment: Can you give some details about your implementation?

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn Seriously? He's talking about separate threads here, that's quite clear.

Comment: @crazylpfan actually i want to communicate with the server from client side along Network using socket programming in java. At server side i'll have two threads, which will listen for its own designated socket from client side, in one thread it will receive some condition data, while in other threads socket connection it will get File. I was implementing it in one thread, there i got success by getting message from one socket, but when i wished to receive data from other socket at the same time, then it hangs.

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn can i implements two socket connection in one thread

Comment: Can you update your post with a sample of your client side code so I can see how you've implemented this?

Comment: Not a real question. Not even a question mark.

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? Servers usually listen, and accept incoming connection requests from clients, on only one socket.  Client<>server threads are then created/allocated only when a client connects.

Comment: @MartinJames actually i have made connection successfully through one thread in the SERVER, but when i read data from one socket then other doesn't work in the nested loop and when i read data from other socket then the rivals one did't work...  can i upload my code to show why i can't read data at the same time

Answer (score 1):

for single processor device two threads will never run simultaneously. Both thread will be given time slots to perform their tasks. But as you are creating two different threads two receive data from socket then there will be no data loss due to alternative thread scheduling. you can simply do the followings

```
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
         //do something
        }
     }
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(){
         public void run(){
          //do something
          }
      }
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
```

in you case there will be no problem in receiving data.